# Implementing iPad .xib after already finishing iPhone part

Tags: ios, xcode

I have finished writing an iPhone part of my application using nib files and now want to extend the application to iPad as well. Now I have tried to add .xib files from finder ( copying and iPad .xib file and renaming it with the correct name and dragging the file to xCode to add it to the list). From the beginning I had planed the iPad version so my iphone .xib was originally named xxx_iPhone.xib. After copying the iPad nib file and naming it xxx_iPad.xib I wanted to add all the connections but found that none of them where there! If I copy paste and add the iphone xib with a different name the connections are present, but then there's the problem that is iphone and not iPad .xib.

Can someone help me? If more information is necessary or if my question is not clear, i can explain myself again.

Thank you!

Comment: There is an automatoc feature in Xcode, it copies the xibs into an ipad_resources folder for you.

Comment: I haven't heard of that feature before. However, I have used XIBs with the ~iphone and ~ipad suffix, which means that calling `[[MyViewController alloc] init]` automatically loads the appropriate XIB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the class of the iPad xib.

[image]

This class must be the ViewController of the xib from iPhone.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was such an easy fix!

Comment: De nada xD good, when you add an .xib from New File go in the same way.